# Simple Algebra to solve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could I get a walk through solving the problem:

```
100 = Y - (Y x 0.0875)
```

I started by subtracting Y on both sides:

```
100 - Y = (Y x 0.0875)
```

And the dividing 0.0875 on both sides:

```
(100-Y) / 0.0875 = Y
```

But now I am at a loss, this actually seems like an impossible to solve math problem to me at the moment, probably because I should go to be already lol, because Y will always be on both sides...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}100 &= Y - (Y \times 0.0875)\\100 &= Y(1) - (Y \times 0.0875)\\100&= Y (1 - 0.0875)\\100&= Y (.9125)\\\frac{100}{.9125}&=Y\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**

$$100=(1-0.0875)\cdot Y$$

Comment: vHow did you get the 1 in there "legally", I kind of get it Y minus a portion of Y in Y - (Y x 0.0875)

Comment: @BrianOgden $Y=1 \cdot Y$